# how to create a custom stacktrace in java with additional info (like parameters)?

Tags: java, function, jar, stack-trace

I was assigned a task to create a custom stacktrace like output to a log file for some specified functions, but instead of just using the class and method names I would also have to output the parameters and their values.

This is supposed to be a separate jar that could run on any java project, after.

I don't even know if such thing is possible, let alone where to start.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Huh, weird idea, and tracking that might slowdown application

Comment: I modified my reply as I found this lib: https://github.com/cretz/stackparam

Comment: You seems to be new here: it would be great if you will tell me if that did help you - if so you can just upvote and accept answer, if not then explain what exactly you need.

Comment: Your solution was good thanks. But I can't upvote you cause don't have rep power sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: there is other library that does that by using native VM api: https://github.com/cretz/stackparam it also modifies Throwable class to always print that modified stacktrace.

The only possible way I can think of is using agents and instrumentalization, but agent needs to be added to startup command line.
Then I would register transformer to transform every class (remember that some basic java classes might be already loaded) using ASM library and add code to beginning of every method invocation to manually track each method class and pass it to my library that would track them:

```
// note that parameters names might not exist in runtime if code was compiled without a flag to include them.
public void doSomething(String name, int something) {
    MyLib.enterMethod(ThisClass.class, new MethodSignature(void.class, String.class, int.class), new Argument("name", name), new Argument("something", something));
    try {
        // original code
    } finally { // so we don't need to care about return in the middle of original code or exceptions
        MyLib.exitMethod();
    }
}
```

`enterMethod` would add invocation frame to some queue and `exitMethod` would remove last added frame. Note that you should have separate queue for each thread, use some `Map<Thread, MyFrame>` or `ThreadLocal` it might be good idea to use some weak references for threads.

And then you could use frames from that queue to create own stacktrace.
But doing something like that might decrease performance a lot - not even just because cost of this code, but adding that to every setter/getter might cause that methods to never be inlined and affect performance even more.

**So it is possible but I really don't recommend doing something like that.**
Also some other transformers added by other libraries might affect results, it might be good idea to also compare your stacktrace with original stacktrace to find any missing methods that you didn't transform - like native ones, and add them to your stacktrace but without that additional data.

If you really need to support native methods too - then you can create more advanced transformer that would add `enterMethod`/`exitMethod` before and after call to native method.

Also if this is only for debugging you could use debugging API so it would only work as a debugger.